# Getting error during logon in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

After successfully create the user, When I logon into this. I get error like below:

User username lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

Comment: In order for a user to be able to connect to an Oracle instance it has to have `create session` system privilege granted. You can grant that privilege either directly `grant create session to <<user_name>>` or through a role(built-in `connect` role or a user defined role) `grant connect to <<user_name>>`

Answer (score 1):

grant create session to USERNAME;

Answer (score 0):

**sqlplus> connect / as sysdba

sqlplus> grant connect to username**